# Gratis Windows PDF printer

Tags: windows, gratis, pdf, printing, pdf-generation

My Windows "print to PDF" functionality no longer works. I am unable to make it work, and unwilling to reinstall Windows.

I am seeking a gratis background spooler service for Windows, which I can see as an option whenever I print something. Other than that, it should be unobtrusive.

I have searched and found a few candidates. Rather than try them all and compare them, I would prefer if someone who has already done so makes me a recommendation.

Comment: Yet another S.E traditionalist - downvote with no explanation :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried : FreePDF for Windows - A simply and free virtual PDF printer

- https://freepdf-xp.en.softonic.com/
  or
- https://freepdf.en.lo4d.com/windows
  [image]

I have been using this for >10 years.

---

It will install a printer service(i.e. virtual printer) and if you click on menu-> printer(e.g. word or any), it will pop-up as a real printer and print your content to PDF and save it to your defined directory.

A detailed installation manual can be found here:
http://www.sternwarte.uni-erlangen.de/pub/sterzer/software/freepdf/freepdfxp/freepdfxpadmin.pdf

Comment: Does it de what I asked? Please read [answer]. Does it install as a spooler service, so that I can use "print to PDF from other apps?

Comment: I just edited the post(link changed), let me know if you still have question. or still unhelpful, I can delete the post.